# Use Flyspell-prog-mode with go-autocomplete

Tags: go, emacs, autocomplete, flyspell

Using flyspell-prog-mode in emacs causes go-automplete to choke. Is there anyway I can make these two modes play nicely together?

I have researched using another spell checker but did not find one that has same capabilities as flyspell (i.e only check comments and strings, and do it on the fly). Any tips most appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general issue with `auto-complete`.  Just do

```
(ac-flyspell-workaround)
```

after setting up `auto-complete`.

Answer (score 0):

jpkotta was correct. Complete solution for reference was:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'go-mode 
 (require 'go-autocomplete) 
 (ac-flyspell-workaround))
```